# Can't get Highstock "scroll" to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

trying to compare two sensor readings - the data is coming from thingspeak.  I've got the zoom part working, but for some reason I cant get the scroll to work.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  // variables for the first series
  var series_1_channel_id = 43330;
  var series_1_field_number = 4;
  var series_1_read_api_key = '7ZPHNX2SXPM0CA1K';
  var series_1_results = 480;
  var series_1_color = '#d62020';
  var series_1_name = 'Zims Sensor';

  // variables for the second series
  var series_2_channel_id = 45473;
  var series_2_field_number = 2;
  var series_2_read_api_key = 'N12T3CWQB5IWJAU9';
  var series_2_results = 480;
  var series_2_color = '#00aaff';
  var series_2_name = 'UVM30a';

  // chart title
  var chart_title = 'UV Sensors Zim / UVM30A';
  // y axis title
  var y_axis_title = 'UV Index';

  // user's timezone offset
  var my_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  // chart variable
  var my_chart;

  // when the document is ready
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    // add a blank chart
    addChart();
    // add the first series
    addSeries(series_1_channel_id, series_1_field_number, series_1_read_api_key, series_1_results, series_1_color, series_1_name);
    // add the second series
    addSeries(series_2_channel_id, series_2_field_number, series_2_read_api_key, series_2_results, series_2_color, series_2_name);
  });

  // add the base chart
  function addChart() {
    // variable for the local date in milliseconds
    var localDate;

    // specify the chart options
    var chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart-container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x',                             // added here
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        events: { }
      },
      title: { text: chart_title },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: { radius: 3 },
          animation: true,
          step: false,
          borderWidth: 0,
          turboThreshold: 0
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        // reformat the tooltips so that local times are displayed
        formatter: function() {
          var d = new Date(this.x + (my_offset*60000));
          var n = (this.point.name === undefined) ? '' : '<br>' + this.point.name;
          return this.series.name + ':<b>' + this.y + '</b>' + n + '<br>' + d.toDateString() + '<br>' + d.toTimeString().replace(/\(.*\)/, "");
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
   barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
   barBorderRadius: 7,
   barBorderWidth: 0,
   buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
   buttonBorderWidth: 0,
   buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
   buttonBorderRadius: 7,
   rifleColor: 'yellow',
   trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
   trackBorderWidth: 1,
   trackBorderColor: 'silver',
   trackBorderRadius: 7
   },
        title: { text: 'Date' }
      },
      yAxis: { title: { text: y_axis_title } },
      exporting: { enabled: true },
      legend: { enabled: true },
      
      credits: {
        text: 'ThingSpeak.com',
        href: 'https://thingspeak.com/',
        style: { color: '#D62020' }
      }
    };

    // draw the chart
    my_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
  }

  // add a series to the chart
  function addSeries(channel_id, field_number, api_key, results, color, name) {
       
    var field_name = 'field' + field_number;

    // get the data with a webservice call
    $.getJSON('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/' + channel_id + '/fields/' + field_number + '.json?offset=0&round=2&results=' + results + '&api_key=' + api_key, function(data) {

      // blank array for holding chart data
      var chart_data = [];

      // iterate through each feed
      $.each(data.feeds, function() {
        var point = new Highcharts.Point();
        // set the proper values
        var value = this[field_name];
        point.x = getChartDate(this.created_at);
        point.y = parseFloat(value);
        // add location if possible
        if (this.location) { point.name = this.location; }
        // if a numerical value exists add it
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(value))) { chart_data.push(point); }
      });

      // add the chart data
      my_chart.addSeries({ data: chart_data, name: data.channel[field_name], color: color });
    });
  }

  // converts date format from JSON
  function getChartDate(d) {
    // offset in minutes is converted to milliseconds and subtracted so that chart's x-axis is correct
    return Date.parse(d) - (my_offset * 60000);
  }

</script>
​
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
  body { background-color: white; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #chart-container { width: 800px; height: 400px; display: block; position:absolute; bottom:0; top:0; left:0; right:0; margin: 5px 15px 15px 0; overflow: hidden; }
</style>​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//thingspeak.com/exporting.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container">
   // <img alt="Ajax loader" src="//thingspeak.com/assets/ajax-loader.gif" style="position: absolute; margin: auto; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

I would also like to get the chart updating automatically, so any help on that score would also be appreciated.  The final issue I am having is trying to get the legend to display the sensor names properly:  UV Index (red) should read "Zims Sensor" and UV Index (blue) should read "UVM30A"

Comment: Regarding legend, here: `name: data.channel[field_name]` you are setting name for the series and legend item. Change it if you want different result. Regarding dynamic update - after you added series (`chart.addSeries()`), setup connection (websockets or AJAX every n-seconds/minutes) and add to the correct series new points using `chart.series[index].addPoint(new_point)`. And for the first question, set [`chart.panKey`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.panKey) to "shift" of something similar.

Comment: Hi Pawe, thanks for your help - I really am out of my depth here!  I have finally got the scroll (or panning) working, but I just can't seem to figure out how to actually name the series. I have tried everything I can think of - and it is now at least naming the data "series 1" and "series 2" - but how do I get the actual names to be used??  I have set it up on JSFiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/SESupply/9xn65qrL/2/  Is there any chance you could have a look at it?  Thanks

Comment: in your addSeries call funcion, add reference to name of serie. Then in my_chart.addSeries() add reference to your name. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9xn65qrL/3/

Comment: @Sebastian, wow - that's awesome! Thanks - it seems so easy when you know what you are doing.    I still don't understand how to implement scrolling properly - I set the zoomType to 'x', and I can set the panning to work - but how can I get the scrollbar along the bottom of the chart??

Comment: You need to enable scrollbar by option like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9xn65qrL/8/) and then set min/max on xAxis.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastion - that works perfectly.  Now all I've got left to figure out is how to do live updates...